# Is there any way to share more than one image as sticker to Instagram Story?

Tags: android, android-intent, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-story

This documentation shows how to send only one sticker, but i want to send more than one. Is there any way to do that?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/

```
private void sendToInstagram(){
    // Instantiate implicit intent with ADD_TO_STORY action,
    // background asset, sticker asset, and attribution link
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setDataAndType(selectedPhotoUri, "image/*");
    intent.putExtra("interactive_asset_uri", selectedStickerUri);

    // Verify if the Activity will resolve implicit intent
    this.grantUriPermission(
            "com.instagram.android", selectedStickerUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    if (this.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null) {
        this.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SEND_TO_INSTAGRAM);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until today there's no way to do that, at least I couldn't find one.